# Issues after cloning repo in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After cloning a repo I am getting two errors that I haven't seen before.

One of them is The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed.

```html
Error  The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'AppName, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'AppName.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() AppName.Android
```

I tried:

Cleaning obj/bin folders
Cleaning Nuget cache
Opening as admin
Changing project path to a shorter one
Updating visual studio
Updating Xamarin Libraries
Updating Android SDKs

Also,

I am getting an error saying that FirebaseUser type cannot be found, yet on my other PC it works just fine, of course the library is included, so even though the lib is included it cannot find the type, weird.

```html
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'FirebaseUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Appname C:\Projects\Appname \Appname \Appname \Services\IFirebaseAuthenticator.cs 15 Active
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've occasionally gotten this error for unclear reasons (different ones than yours for sure) and fixed it by first `Rebuild`ing the PCL project in particular, followed by `Rebuild`ing the platform-specific project. Rebuilding at the solution level would not fix the problem.